# How to export query result to text file using command line

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to export my query result to .txt or .csv file but using command.

I want to do something like this:

```
BULK "EXPORT" (Select * from MyTable) to 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\filename.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

How can i do this?

Comment: There is no `BULK EXPORT`, only `BULK INSERT`. Is `bcp` an option?

Comment: Im trying to apply bcp, but i dont know how

Comment: why not sqlcmd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SQLCMD as below -

```
    sqlcmd -S . -d DbName -E -s',' -W -Q "SELECT * FROM [Table]" > C:\Test.csv
```

You can also try BCP as below -

```
   bcp [BookDb].[dbo].[Books] out C:\Test1.csv -T
```

Follow below link for more information - 
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/working-with-the-bcp-command-line-utility/

Answer (score 0):

I have used below statement to export tab separated data in csv

```
mysql -h$ip -u$user -p$password -P3310 $dbName -B -e "select * from a" > a_data.csv
```